Is there a way to trigger a Value change event withing the ControlTemplate for a Slider
I am trying to come up with a ControlTemplate that will make a Slider look like a NumericUpDown control.
It has a Grid with three columns, where there will be a decrement button, a TextBlock showing the current value, and an increment button.
Yes, I know there are some imitations of NumericUpDown control in WPF which use code-behind, or custom controls in some libraries, but I am looking for a sneaky way to increment and decrement the value by adding EventTriggers to Click events of the buttons on the template.
Could I achieve my goal by invoking ValueChanged or other slider events in those EventTriggers?
Note: A Storyboard with a DoubleAnimation almost worked, but, alas, I could not bind the "To" property of the animation to the incremented or decremented Value property of the Slider itself, because of the Freezable issue.

Well, I couldn't find an answer to this question in its current form, but I did find a way to make the Slider work like a NumericUpDown control: I bound the buttons to two commands IncrementCommand and DecrementCommand. The buttons also passed the control name of the slider as CommandParameter. Then, in the viewmodel serving as the DataContext, I implemented the commands and incremented or decremented the property which the named Slider was bound to.

The standard Slider has the commands to incrememt or decrement values and a simple custom ControlTemplate for Slider will suffice.
<Style x:Key="NumericUpDownStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Ticks" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- Decrement button -->
                    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0"
                                  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge"
                                  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="16"
                                  Content="&#xE973;"
                                  Focusable="False"/>

                    <Border Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderBrush="Gray"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Border>

                    <!-- Increment button -->
                    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="2"
                                  Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge"
                                  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="16"
                                  Content="&#xE974;"
                                  Focusable="False"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


Thank you; I had seen another answer with a ScrollBar template just like this one, so I was trying to imitate it with Slider. Your version might be what I was looking for.

Okay, I implemented this solution and works perfectly, without using any codebehind or command implementation. Thanks so much!

In this case, I recommend you to create a Custom Control derived from RangeBase.
Example implementation:
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfCustomControlsCore
{
    public class NumericUpDown : RangeBase
    {
        static NumericUpDown()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NumericUpDown), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NumericUpDown)));
            SmallChangeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NumericUpDown), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0));
            MaximumProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NumericUpDown), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(100.0));
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(NumericUpDown), new(UpValueCommand, OnUpValueExecute, OnUpDownValueCanExecute));
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(NumericUpDown), new(DownValueCommand, OnDownValueExecute, OnUpDownValueCanExecute));
        }

        private static void OnUpValueExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NumericUpDown numericUpDown = (NumericUpDown)sender;
            numericUpDown.Value += numericUpDown.SmallChange;
        }

        private static void OnUpDownValueCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NumericUpDown numericUpDown = (NumericUpDown)sender;
            e.CanExecute = numericUpDown.SmallChange > 0.0;
        }

        private static void OnDownValueExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NumericUpDown numericUpDown = (NumericUpDown)sender;
            numericUpDown.Value -= numericUpDown.SmallChange;
        }

        public static readonly RoutedUICommand UpValueCommand = new("Up Value", nameof(UpValueCommand), typeof(NumericUpDown));
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand DownValueCommand = new("Down Value", nameof(DownValueCommand), typeof(NumericUpDown));


        /// <summary>Duplicate property, for passing the value back from Value to the source.</summary>
        public double Value2
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(Value2Property);
            set => SetValue(Value2Property, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value2.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Value2Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(Value2),
                typeof(double),
                typeof(NumericUpDown),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0)
                {
                    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                    PropertyChangedCallback = async (d, e) =>
                    {
                        NumericUpDown nud = (NumericUpDown)d;
                        if (!e.NewValue.Equals(nud.Value))
                        {
                            await nud.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => nud.Value2 = nud.Value, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send);
                        }
                    }
                });

        protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
        {
            base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
            SetValue(Value2Property, newValue);
        }

    }
}

In Themes\Generic.xaml
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NumericUpDown}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NumericUpDown}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
                                     Text="{Binding Value,
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Button Grid.Row="0" FontSize="10"
                                        Command="{x:Static local:NumericUpDown.UpValueCommand}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="▲"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Grid.Row="1"
                                        FontSize="10"
                                        Command="{x:Static local:NumericUpDown.DownValueCommand}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="▼"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

Example of use:
    public class DoubleItem
    {
        public double Number { get; set; }
    }

    <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Border Background="LightGreen" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2"
                    Padding="20" Margin="10">
                <StackPanel MinWidth="100">
                    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
                        <local:DoubleItem Number="-3"/>
                    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" Margin="5"/>
                    <custctrl:NumericUpDown Margin="5"
                                    Value="{Binding Number}"
                                    Maximum="10" Minimum="5"
                                    />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border Background="LightGreen" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2"
                    Padding="20" Margin="10">
                <StackPanel MinWidth="100">
                    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
                        <local:DoubleItem Number="-3"/>
                    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" Margin="5"/>
                    <custctrl:NumericUpDown Margin="5"
                                    Value="{Binding Number}"
                                    Maximum="10" Minimum="5"
                                    Value2="{Binding Number}"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Number, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentControl>



Thank you, I had also tried custom controls but a specialized template which utilizes Slider's own commands was going to be simpler and that's what I ended up doing, based on the accepted answer.
